# Concatenar fecha y hora en una variable

Tags: angular, typescript, date, datetime, time

Necesito crear un `date` completo con fecha y hora, tengo dos funciones que reciben una la fecha y otra la hora y quiero concatenar-las para mostrar el siguiente formato: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

```
dateChange(selectedDate) {
   //console.log(selectedDate);
   const date = `${selectedDate.year}-${selectedDate.month}-${selectedDate.day}`;
   console.log(this.data);}
}

onChange() {
   console.log(this.hourTime);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Porque no utilizas los pipes?
En el arvhivo .html podes hacer lo siguiente;
`{{ dateObj | date:'medium' }}` y la salida es ***// output is 'Jun 15, 2015, 9:43:11 PM'***

También podes jugar con las fechas desde el .ts pero es mas simple usando los pipes
Pegale un vistazo a la documentación sobre los pipes:

> https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: Ese no es el formato solicitado